# Enable storage permission on Google Cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a Google Cloud VM instance, but I overlooked setting the Storage permission to read-write when creating it.

Now further down the line, I'm looking to experiment with cloud storage, but my instance is read-only.

How can this be changed? I understand it may be possible by relaxing the storage buckets policy, but I'd prefer my instance had write access to all future project buckets.

I presume there is an option in gcloud to change the devstorage parameter?

[image: Storage disabled]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the permissions of your VM instance now but only when it is shut down. Check the following documentation:

[Changing the service account and access scopes for an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes)

If you want to update the API permissions for the kuberntes clusters VM instance then you cannot do that unless you create a new cluster and give the API access to the nodes associated with the clusters.

Answer (score 7):

So, you can't change the option to grant the VM permission, but I did find that you can just run

> gcloud auth login

then you can sign in with your management account from the VM and you'll be able to run commands that way.

Comment: for the temporary solution, this is the best. I only need to push the backup file one time only

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can't change the scopes of the VM. You will have to create a new one to change them.

When you create a new one you can reuse the disk of the old VM, if that helps avoid the pain.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they have added the option to change it now, without creating another VM.
Once you have stopped the instances, click on the instances you want to change. On the top there is a Edit button, you can click on it and change any the permissions.

Hope the image helps
[edit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzOT5.png)

Once you have changed the permission to read_write and it still says Access Denied. Go in your instance SSH browser window and enter 'gcloud auth login', follow the steps and hopefully it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop your vm first, then click on edit and change the cloud api access scopes for storage.

You may find more information here: https://ismailyenigul.medium.com/setting-access-scope-of-google-cloud-vm-instances-c8637718f453