# Google Compute Engine reports a read-only disc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, scp, gcloud

I have created a [standard persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#create_disk) and successfully mounted it in Read/Write configuration on a node in my Kubernetes cluster.

I would now like to populate that disk with some content I currently have locally. The [`scp` tool](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) in the `gcloud` SDK seems like the ideal way to do this.

However, when I run:

```
gcloud compute scp ~/Desktop/subway-explorer-api/logbooks.sqlite gke-webapp-default-pool-49338587-d78l:/mnt/subway-explorer-datastore --zone us-central1-a
```

I get:

```
scp: /mnt/subway-explorer-datastore: Read-only file system
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

My questions are:

- What is my error here? Why is the disk being reported as being read-only?
- How do I fix it?
- Is this indeed a good use of the `gcloud scp` utility (I got to here by looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37598556/1993206)), or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Deploy files are available [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/subway-explorer-deploy).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31118463/1993206 implied this is due to permissions settings on the `Storage` line of the VM instance, but the VM in question has `Storage` access scopes set to `Full`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misinterpreted the folder the disk got mounted to, and I was trying to write to a folder that didn't actually exist. The error message led me to misdiagnose this as a permissions error, when in reality it was operator error.

For further details see [this answer on the Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428915/scp-not-able-to-write-to-a-mounted-volume-complains-its-read-only/429062#429062).